# How to change device driver via scripting

Tags: windows-7, command-line, drivers

We have a default Windows 7 image which contains a lot of different device drivers. As a result, two compatible drivers for a network card are found, but one of the two result in a problem. We now have an instruction for our assembly guys to select the correct driver via device manager.

Is there a way to change the device driver via command line so that I can script this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to change the device driver via command line?

There are two possibilities, `pnputil` and `devcon`:

> Generally speaking, the best tool to manage device drivers is “Device Manager”. That is a GUI snap-in for Microsoft Management Console (MMC Jump ). You can start it by launching devmgmt.msc. But that's not an option in some specific cases, namely:
>
> - Scripting.
> - Windows Server installed in Server Core option.
>
> Microsoft provides two such tools that differ both in their
>   capabilities and availability.
>
> **Plug-and-Play (PnP) Utility (PNPUtil.exe)**
>
> Basic Features:
>
> - List drivers - PNPUTIL.EXE -e
> - Add driver.
> - Install driver.
> - Remove driver.
>
> Pros:
>
> - Included out of the box with all current Windows versions.
> - Syntax complexity is medium.
>
> Cons:
>
> - Does not provide advanced functionality such as:
>
>   - Disable device.
>   - Select one specific driver for a specific device from the list of compatible drivers that are currently installed in the system.
>
> Availability:
>
> - Inbox with all current Windows versions.
>
> More information:
>
> - For a detailed description, comprehensive list of features, syntax and command-line examples please see official documentation at
>     [PnPUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee816995.aspx).
>
> **Device Console (DevCon.exe)**
>
> Features (also Pros):
>
> - All device and driver management functionality that can be found in Device Management MMC including advanced functionality such as:
>
>   - Disable device.
>   - Select one specific driver for a specific device from the list of compatible drivers that are currently installed in the system.
>
> Cons:
>
> - Not available out-of-the box.
> - Syntax complexity is high.
>
> Availability:
>
> - See [How to Obtain the Current Version of Device Console Utility (DevCon.exe)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/182.how-to-obtain-the-current-version-of-device-console-utility-devcon-exe.aspx) for detailed instructions.
>
> More information:
>
> - For a detailed description, comprehensive list of features, syntax and command-line examples please see official documentation at
>     [DevCon](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/182.how-to-obtain-the-current-version-of-device-console-utility-devcon-exe.aspx).

Source [How to Manage Device Drivers with Command Line](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/181.how-to-manage-device-drivers-with-command-line.aspx)

Comment: Hey thx a lot will dive into this tomorrow